# Tutorial for Haskell Restful-API Webserver

Tags: haskell

Using free and open source Haskell and with minimal or ideally no external libraries, I need to build a very simple RESTful-API/database server and a CLI to manage it. I need to use it for serving up webpages, text files, or selected lines of json from a text file. After this is done, I would like to give it a GUI. My problem is I can't find any tutorials that explain how to do any of this.

Does anyone know of any tutorials that fit these requirements?
Much thanks

Comment: There are at least 3 web frameworks in the Haskell ecosystem, from simplest to most complex; Scotty, Yesod and Snap.

A google search shows up a bunch of tutorials: https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=haskell+rest+web+server+howto

Comment: Thank you @ErikdeCastroLopo. I had been searching and searching but never thought to use the keyword howto. That was the charm.